# how much coolant required in chevrolet spark

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, spark

Which coolant I can use in my Chevrolet spark and how much coolant and water required

Comment: It should tell you this in your handbook (often available on the internet if you don't have one). It will vary according to the specific model, and the concentration of coolant to water will vary according to your climate.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this website](http://www.autocats.ws/manual/chevrolet/tis0409/EN/documents_2007/Matiz/sm-m/7m2_0B0.en.html), the coolant capacity for the 2007 Chevrolet Spark is 4.2L (4.4 qts) for the 1.0L engine. If your vehicle differs from this, you can cross reference on that page to get your specific vehicle.

You can use whatever type of coolant you desire (red, green, yellow, orange, etc.), but realize each has its own change interval. It will also have its own mix ratio, but most require a 50/50 mix with water. Purchasing premixed coolant (50/50) will save a lot of time/hassle, plus you'll know the ratio is exactly what you need. Brand of coolant is fairly irrelevant as they are nearly the same between types.

Comment: My car is 2007 model spark 1.0l ,which brand you prefer for coolant

Comment: @SubrataKar - Please see edits.